# Popover is opening with no data in sapUi5

Tags: sapui5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbhl1.png)
The popover is opening but I am not getting any data.
Please find the code in the image attached.

Comment: build an example use this template https://jsfiddle.net/nistv4n/93mx0yvt/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind the model to your popover. Add this line after addDependent line:
this._popover.bindElement("/linkedDocs");

Comment: Thanks but I am still not getting data in popover on opening